# python - running multiple commands with subprocess over ssh

Tags: python, email, ssh, smtp, subprocess

I am trying to open a subprocess to send an email over the SMTP protocol on my server. To achieve this, I need a TLS Secure Channel, so I need the SSL module. I do not succeed since I can not manage to interact over openssl through a subprocess.

This is how I envision how my script needs to work.

*1. **Open ssl connection**:  openssl s_client -connect smtp.server.com:587 -starttls smtp*

*1.1. **Communicate over this channel to login**:  AUTH PLAIN ENCODEDLOGINSTRING==*

*1.2. **Communicate over this channel to send mails**:  MAIL FROM:myemail@server.com*

My script ought not to return anything, other then "mail was send".

How do I accomplish this?

**Note: smtplib is not legal to use for my assignment.**

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's best to use a socket for this (not a subprocess) and then use the command "STARTTLS" and then wrap the socket with ssl in order to get a secure tls connection. After that you can proceed to send your *rcpt to:* commands et cetera and send the actual mail through the socket.

Sidenote: I used this script in a subprocess and I needed that to print things in html format; but here is my code that did the trick. If you plan on using it, you'll need to set and FORMAT (with newlines and stuff (so that the smtp server understands)) these variables first: *sender, to, subject, body, server, username, password and port*.

```
# check if server is valid
try:
    socket.gethostbyname(server)
except socket.gaierror:
    print("""
    <p>
    Something seems wrong with the server...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()

# make a connection with the server
mailserver = (server, port)
socket.mailsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.mailsocket.connect(mailserver)
step1 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step1 = step1.decode()
if (step1[:3] != '220'):
    print("""
    <p>
    Something seems wrong with the server...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()

# use tls connection with server
starttls = "STARTTLS" + "\r\n"
socket.mailsocket.send(starttls.encode())
step2 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step2 = step2.decode()
if (step2[:3] != '220'):
    print("""
    <p>
    Something seems wrong with the TLS connection...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()

# now use SSL
ssl = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.mailsocket, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
socket.mailsocket = ssl

# set username and password and encode
base64_str = ("\x00"+username+"\x00"+password).encode()
base64_str = base64.b64encode(base64_str)
auth = "AUTH PLAIN ".encode()+base64_str+"\r\n".encode()
socket.mailsocket.send(auth)
step3 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step3 = step3.decode()
if (step3[:3] != '235'):
    print("""
    <p>
    It seems like your username/password combination is incorrect...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()

# set sender address
sender = "mail from: " + sender + "\r\n"
socket.mailsocket.send(sender.encode())
step4 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step4 = step4.decode()
if (step4[:3] != '250'):
    print("""
    <p>
    It seems like the sender address is incorrect...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()

# set to address
to = "rcpt to: " + to + "\r\n"
socket.mailsocket.send(to.encode())
step5 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step5 = step5.decode()
if (step5[:3] != '250'):
    print("""
    <p>
    It seems like the destination address is incorrect...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()

# send data command
data = "data\r\n"
socket.mailsocket.send(data.encode())
step6 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step6 = step6.decode()
if (step6[:3] != '354'):
    print("""
    <p>
    It seems like the server responds different on the DATA command...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()

# send message subject and body
socket.mailsocket.send(subject.encode())
socket.mailsocket.send(body.encode())
step7 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step7 = step7.decode()
if (step7[:3] != '250'):
    print("""
    <p>
    It seems like there is something wrong with your message body...
    </p>
    """)
    exit()
else:
    print("""
    <p>
    Your message is queued and will sent as soon as possible!
    </p>
    """)
quit = "QUIT\r\n"
socket.mailsocket.send(quit.encode())

step8 = socket.mailsocket.recv(1024)
step8 = step8.decode()
if (step8[:3] == '221'):
    print("""
    <p>
    Closing connection; bye!
    </p>
    """)
socket.mailsocket.close()
```